# I could not see the output in Eclipse why?

Tags: java, eclipse, console, output

The issue is when i try to see the programming result in eclipse i could not i have the console window but nothing to appear there when i run the code to sure no an error i made, this is the code which i tried to run it

```
package com.java24hours;

public class NewRoot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int number = 100;
        if (args.length > 0) {

            number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

            System.out.println(" The square root of "
                    + number
                    + " is "
                    + Math.sqrt(number));

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: make sure you have provided the value for args

Comment: Right click on the class you are running, then click properties, and click Run/Debug settings when the window opens, then click on the Main method and click edit, then on the arguments tab, put in the number that you want the squareroot of.

Comment: `if (args.length > 0)` - if your run configuration in Eclipse doesn't provide arguments you won't see any output.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not providing any runtime value for the main method. To provide the value for your main method :

Right Click on **NewRoot**

Goto **Run As ---> Run Configuration.**

In your **Run Configuration** Window Click on **Argumets** tab :

Provide any value like 100 in **Program Arguments** field

Then click on **Apply** button on down and then Click on **Run** button

You will get output as : **The square root of 100 is 10.0**